# How to test a function which reload a location with Teaspoon-mocha and Sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon, sinon-chai, teaspoon

I'm a beginner in testing and I would like to understand how could I test a function which as a purpose has to reload a page every 10s. 
I would like to understand what I need to mock with an example.

The function:

```
$(document).ready(check);

  function check () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      location.reload(true);
    }, 10000);
  }
```

This function essentially works on one page where some data is coming so that why need to refresh every 10s to show the most updated data.
In this case what I thought I should test is if it is called if the timeout working and after 10s the reload begun. Then stop.
I will appreciate an example lo let me understand the testing methodology here.

Comment: It would be better if you investigate and research on this rather than asking it here.

Comment: I did that and that why I'm asking as I saw for Jasmine but I don't find for Sinon.
If you know links where I should see please share it and I will check it for sure